# Simplify setOptionByValue(selectElement, value) function for <select> element. How?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When data is received from a JSON api, one of the data properties is used to set the selected option value of a select html element.

The following code sets the option to be selected based on the select html element and the corresponding select option value passed in.

Is there a shorter version of this nowadays?

Take a look:

```js
// Custom function to set select option by value
const setOptionByValue = (selectElement, value) => {
  let options = selectElement.getElementsByTagName('option');
  for (let i = 0, optionsLength = options.length; i < optionsLength; i++) {
    // console.log(options[i].value);
    if (options[i].value == value) {
      selectElement.selectedIndex = i;
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// The select element
const selectStatus = document.getElementById('selectStatus');

// Initially set status to Draft.
setOptionByValue(selectStatus, 'Draft');
```

```html
<label for="selectStatus">Status:</label>
<select id="selectStatus">
<option value="0" selected>Select...</option>
<option value="Draft">Draft</option>
<option value="Pending">Pending</option>
<option value="Complete">Complete</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the value to the select element's value

```js
// Custom function to set select option by value
const setOptionByValue = (selectElement, value) => {
  selectElement.value = value;
}

// The select element
const selectStatus = document.getElementById('selectStatus');

// Initially set status to Draft.
setOptionByValue(selectStatus, 'Draft');
```

```html
<label for="selectStatus">Status:</label>
<select id="selectStatus">
<option value="0" selected>Select...</option>
<option value="Draft">Draft</option>
<option value="Pending">Pending</option>
<option value="Complete">Complete</option>
</select>
```

Should the value of the option differ from its content and you wish to select by content:

```js
// Custom function to set select option by value
const setOptionByValue = (selectElement, value) => {
  selectElement.querySelectorAll('option').forEach((e) => {
    if (e.innerHTML == value) {
      selectElement.value = e.value;
    }
  })
}

// The select element
const selectStatus = document.getElementById('selectStatus');

// Initially set status to Draft.
setOptionByValue(selectStatus, 'Draft');
```

```html
<label for="selectStatus">Status:</label>
<select id="selectStatus">
  <option value="0" selected>Select...</option>
  <option value="Draft">Draft</option>
  <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
  <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Wow. So, is there anything the function I've posted does that just directly setting by value doesn't? I can't believe I've missed this.

Comment: @suchislife the functions do exactly the same thing :)